What causes score multipliers in Delibird Delivery?
I was watching someone play the Pokemon Stadium 2 minigame Delibird Delivery when I noticed sometimes they would get a 2x or 3x multiplier when delivering presents. What causes the 2x and 3x multipliers?

Screenshot from Alpharad LIVE

The point multiplier seems to be for delivering the same present multiple times in a row.
According to gamefaqs:

Fill the sack with up to five gifts using the Control Stick and carry it up to
the top. Highest score wins. Earn extra points for picking up the same items in
a row.

According to Bulbapedia:

As Delibird, players pick up presents and deliver them to their conveyor belt while avoiding the Swinub. Players earn extra points if they deliver more of the same present.

